# Is it comfortable to get from Barcelona to Pyrenees (La Molina) for one day skiing trip in January

Tags: public-transport, spain, pyrenees, skiing

Is it comfortable to get from Barcelona to Pyrenees (La Molina) for one day skiing trip in January? By train / bus / car / blablacar? I mean train would be probably the best but is there any? In January roads can be not in the best condition so rented car is rather last option. I will not have my own skiis on the trip (I'll rent them on the spot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[La Molina's own website](http://www.lamolina.cat/en/winter/services/transport-to-slopes/) says that there are train and bus options.

The bus is provided by [Sagalés](http://www.sagales.com/en/trip/24/skibus-to-la-molina-or-masella) and runs once daily, departing Barcelona at 06:30 and (if I understand correctly) departing La Molina at 16:00. I'm not sure how much time that would give you on the slopes. Note that it is dependent on there being enough interest on a given day.

The train is [Renfe Rodalies](http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/cercanias/barcelona/) (middle-distance), and would probably allow you more time on the slopes because the first departure from Barcelona is at 06:08 and the last departure from La Molina is at 19:24. What isn't clear is how to purchase the package which includes the train ticket and the ski pass; perhaps it's best done in person on the previous day.

Comment: brilliant answer!

Comment: Just to confirm with experience: I live in Barcelona and I have gone skying in La Molina - a few decades ago-, at least once by train, and it is perfectly doable. By car it's even easier.